# Novel about an older race of amphibians discovered on Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, underground-civilization, ancient-races

This may have been a YA novel I read in paperback pre-80's. The protagonist was a kid who found a cavern and woke up a member of the race that was in some sort of stasis.

They explore some of the cities under the sea. I'm pretty sure they were amphibious, but may have been water-breathers. The look stuck in my mind is like the creature from the black lagoon.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Sounds like it could be [Stranger from the Depths](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2349510.Stranger_From_the_Depths) by Gerry Turner, which was the subject of a [previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100459/anyone-remember-a-sci-fi-character-named-saa).

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182552/looking-for-a-book-from-late-60s-to-1972-sold-through-the-scholastic-book-club-i for a question about the same book with more details.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209212/teenagers-find-an-ancient-lizard-creature-in-stasis-and-accompany-him-on-adventu (which is newer but has an answer confirmed by OP comment)